# Why does this CUDA example kernel have a for loop?

Tags: cuda

I have been looking at the following example from the official CUDA website:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-cufft

Download here: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/C/Projects/x64/simpleCUFFT.zip

It contains the following kernel:

```
// Complex pointwise multiplication
static __global__ void ComplexPointwiseMulAndScale(Complex *a, const Complex *b, int size, float scale)
{
    const int numThreads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    const int threadID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    for (int i = threadID; i < size; i += numThreads)
    {
        a[i] = ComplexScale(ComplexMul(a[i], b[i]), scale);
    }
}
```

My question is, why is there a for loop here? Doesn't CUDA simultaneously call an array of thread? I removed the thread, replacing it with the following code and it produced the same output.

```
// Complex pointwise multiplication
static __global__ void ComplexPointwiseMulAndScale(Complex *a, const Complex *b, int size, float scale)
{
    const int threadID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    a[threadID] = ComplexScale(ComplexMul(a[threadID], b[threadID]), scale);
}
```

As this is an official example on the CUDA website, I imagine I must be missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version is basically what happens when `numThreads` is equal to `size` (but *only* then).

What the official example does is the following: Suppose `numThreads` is equal to 4 (for simplicity, usually it will be much larger), and consider the array positions (both for `a` and `b`):

```
  a or b                  x x x x x x x x
  thread that works here  0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
```

Then the first thread will work on all array position divisible by 4, et cetera.

The problem with your version is that the *caller* of your function will have to make sure that there are as many threads as `size` is large. For example, if you call your version with a 1-dim grid and both `gridDim.x` and `blockDim.x` being 2, but on vectors of length 8, then half of your vector isn't processed!

The official example works regardless - no matter how many threads the caller assigns to it, the entire vector will be processed.